# Appending input box with jquery, the maxlength property is not being obeyed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

The following code creates a maxLength property that I can view via debugger, however it's not actually limiting the data to the length ?

```
var myRow = '<tr><td></td><td><input maxlength="128" class="myClass" type="text" name="myData[' + i + ']" /></td></tr>';

 $('#myTable tr:last').after(myRow);
```

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/zqCBC/ You'll need to show a full example that shows the problem.

Comment: Also, works fine here. Which browser is it? Even though I believe it is fully supported

Comment: All browsers, actually I think is the conversion to java - my other inputs are explictly bound by path on a spring form. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: You should use `$('#myTable').append(myRow)`

Comment: @Bergi that wouldn't do what I wanted ...

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Why not? Do you use multiple `<tbody>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` elements?